Equivalent of `https.agent` in React Native
I need to make an API request using this cURL
curl -L -i -X PUT –cert ./[device_cert].pem –key ./[device_cert_private_key].pem -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Content-Encoding:  utf-8' -d '{"registrationId": "[registration_id]"}' https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/[ID_Scope]/registrations/[registration_id]/register?api-version=2021-06-01

And I convert it to axios, it seems like this
 const data = {
    registrationId: registrationId,
  };
  const cert = await RNFS.readFile(certificatePath, 'utf8');
  const key = await RNFS.readFile(keyPath, 'utf8');
  console.log('cert', cert);
  console.log('key', key);
 
  try {
    const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
      cert: cert,
      key: key,
    });
    console.log('httpsAgent', httpsAgent);
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/${scopeId}/registrations/${registrationId}/register?api-version=2021-06-01`,
      data: data,
      httpsAgent: httpsAgent,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Encoding': 'utf-8',
      },
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
    return err;
  }

In node we have API called https which provide Agent method to add certificate and private for API request as
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({cert:cert,key:key})

But react native doesn't support https.
So I tried multiple packages such rn-nodeify node-libs-react-native react-native-ssl-pinning
I can't use nodejs-mobile-react-native as app size increases a lot with this package.
How can I use https.Agent in react native?
Thank You

use react-native-fetch https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch or use axios https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios

React Native doesn't natively support https.Agent from Node.js, but you can achieve similar functionality by using libraries that support certificate pinning or custom SSL configurations. We’ll use the packages axios, react-native-ssl-pinning, and react-native-fs.

Refer to this SO for https.Agent and React Native integration. I use react-native-fetch or axios packages.

import React, { useEffect } from  'react';

import { Image, StyleSheet, Platform, View, Text } from  'react-native';

import axios from  'axios';

import { HelloWave } from  '@/components/HelloWave';

import ParallaxScrollView from  '@/components/ParallaxScrollView';

import { ThemedText } from  '@/components/ThemedText';

import { ThemedView } from  '@/components/ThemedView';

const  deviceCert = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;

const  devicePrivateKey = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

...

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`;

const  registrationId = '[registration_id]';

const  idScope = '[ID_Scope]';
export  default  function  HomeScreen() {

useEffect(() => {

const  fetchData = async () => {

try {

const  response = await  axios.put(

`https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/${idScope}/registrations/${registrationId}/register?api-version=2021-06-01`,

{

registrationId: registrationId

},

{

headers: {

'Content-Type': 'application/json',

'Content-Encoding': 'utf-8',

// Note: Certificates and keys are not directly supported by axios config

},

timeout: 3000, // 3 seconds timeout

}

);
console.log(response.data);

} catch (error) {

console.error(error);

}

};
fetchData();

}, []);
return (

<ParallaxScrollView

headerBackgroundColor={{ light: '#A1CEDC', dark: '#1D3D47' }}

headerImage={

<Image

source={require('@/assets/images/partial-react-logo.png')}

style={styles.reactLogo}

/>

}>

<ThemedView  style={styles.titleContainer}>

<ThemedText  type="title">Welcome!</ThemedText>

<HelloWave  />

</ThemedView>

<ThemedView  style={styles.stepContainer}>

<ThemedText  type="subtitle">Step 1: Try it</ThemedText>

<ThemedText>

Edit <ThemedText  type="defaultSemiBold">app/(tabs)/index.tsx</ThemedText> to see changes.

Press{' '}

<ThemedText  type="defaultSemiBold">

{Platform.select({ ios: 'cmd + d', android: 'cmd + m' })}

</ThemedText>{' '}

to open developer tools.

</ThemedText>

</ThemedView>

<ThemedView  style={styles.stepContainer}>

<ThemedText  type="subtitle">Step 2: Explore</ThemedText>

<ThemedText>

Tap the Explore tab to learn more about what's included in this starter app.

</ThemedText>

</ThemedView>

<ThemedView  style={styles.stepContainer}>

<ThemedText  type="subtitle">Step 3: Get a fresh start</ThemedText>

<ThemedText>

When you're ready, run{' '}

<ThemedText  type="defaultSemiBold">npm run reset-project</ThemedText> to get a fresh{' '}

<ThemedText  type="defaultSemiBold">app</ThemedText> directory. This will move the current{' '}

<ThemedText  type="defaultSemiBold">app</ThemedText> to{' '}

<ThemedText  type="defaultSemiBold">app-example</ThemedText>.

</ThemedText>

</ThemedView>

</ParallaxScrollView>

);

}

  

const  styles = StyleSheet.create({

titleContainer: {

flexDirection: 'row',

alignItems: 'center',

gap: 8,

},

stepContainer: {

gap: 8,

marginBottom: 8,

},

reactLogo: {

height: 178,

width: 290,

bottom: 0,

left: 0,

position: 'absolute',

},

});



When using react-native-axios, you might face SSL pinning issues. The GitHub issue provides guidance on using React Native SSL pinning with the Axios library.
using with react-native-fetch ,react-native-fs , react-native-ssl-pinning
const handleRequest = async () => {
    const certificatePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/device_cert.pem';
    const keyPath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/device_cert_private_key.pem';
    const registrationId = 'your_registration_id_here';
    const scopeId = 'your_scope_id_here';

    try {
     
      const cert = await RNFS.readFile(certificatePath, 'utf8');
      const key = await RNFS.readFile(keyPath, 'utf8');
      
      const response = await fetch(`https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/${scopeId}/registrations/${registrationId}/register?api-version=2021-06-01`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({ registrationId: registrationId }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Encoding': 'utf-8',
        },
      });

      // Handle response
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log('Response:', json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Request failed', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleRequest();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Check console for results</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});


Hello @Sampath Thank you for answer. I checked the github issue, in short it says to use TrustKit at Native module to make it work. I was looking for something simple which can help with node, but https.Agent is having some issue in rn-nodeify. I am working now to create native module for all Device provisioning service using java sdk. Thank you again.

@ Refer to this links for Device provisioning service using java sdk
